# Create Application: On-Off Mouse-Keyboard By Microphone Sound Level

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, mouse, disabled-input

I need to make in practice a application running in WIN7.
This application must read continuously the sound(noise) received from the microphone and, if the level of the sound(noise) is higher that a value, to activate to display a Jpeg image on the screen and at the same time to deactivate the mouse and the keyboard. To have a adjusted delay and after the delay time to reactivate the mouse and the keyboard.
This application must start at StartUp of PC.
I need to use this application in a computer class room at every PC with WIN7.
This can be a batch file or a C++ or everything else.
Can somebody help me ???

I found this related to read microphone input level:

static float peak = 5;

while(1)

{
 HRESULT hr;

```
IMMDeviceEnumerator *pEnumerator = NULL;
IMMDevice *pDevice = NULL;
IAudioMeterInformation *pMeterInfo = NULL;

CoInitialize(NULL);

// Get enumerator for audio endpoint devices.
hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator),
                      NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                      __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator),
                      (void**)&pEnumerator);
EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

// Get peak meter for default audio-capturing device.
hr = pEnumerator->GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(eCapture, eConsole, &pDevice);
EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)

hr = pDevice->Activate(__uuidof(IAudioMeterInformation),
                       CLSCTX_ALL, NULL, (void**)&pMeterInfo);
EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr)
```

hr = pMeterInfo->GetPeakValue(&peak);

printf("\rCurrent volume as a scalar is: %f", peak);

Sleep(500); // update every half-second

Exit:

```
if (FAILED(hr))

{
    MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("This program requires Win7."),
               TEXT("Error termination"), MB_OK);
}
SAFE_RELEASE(pEnumerator)
SAFE_RELEASE(pDevice)
SAFE_RELEASE(pMeterInfo)
CoUninitialize();
```

I found this related to On/Off input for keyboard and mouse:

class MyClass

{
  [DllImport("user32.dll")]

private static extern bool BlockInput(bool fBlockIt);

private static void MyMethod()

{

```
BlockInput(true);

Run(@DesktopDir & "\autoit\" & "mu.exe", "")

Thread.Sleep(60000);

BlockInput(false);
```

}

}

I dont cnow how to maried them for a final executable program running at StartUp